# accommodate all s&p 500 companies data frame together

Tags: r, dataframe, download

I can download small number of companies stock market data by this code.

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols(c("MSFT", "AAPL", "GOOGL"), auto.assign = TRUE, from = "2005-01-05",src="google")
```

However when I replace ("MSFT", "AAPL", "GOOGL") this by all companies of s&p 500 by copying the materials from this link

https://www.quantopian.com/posts/symbol-list-of-all-s-and-p-500-companies

global environment shows nothing. Now how can I get all these companies dataframe in my global environment list?

Comment: The symbol list in your link contains a formatting error that may be causing your problem.  'KIM' is followed by a period instead of a comma:  `'KMB', 'KIM'. 'KMI',`

Comment: ok thanks, But when I replace symbols line by line , it gives only first few results in alphabetical order.

Comment: Even with fixing the formatting issue, the code still throws an error. It seems a handful of the parameter names are outdated or the connection no longer exists. I'm getting some 400 and 404 errors indicating bad request or unauthorized request. If you want to read in as many of files as you can without having an error throw the whole thing try...`for(i in quant_list){
  try(getSymbols(i, auto.assign = TRUE, src="google"))
}` with quant_list being the list of values in the link.

Comment: Error: object 'quant_list' not found is coming -D.sen

Comment: @SyedRiazMahmoodAli  How did you define `quant_list` in your code?

Comment: assign the list of names in the link to a variable in list format- use that name in the for loop. In my example I called the list `quant_list`. FYI- the loop will take some time... and will store each name as its own df.

Comment: sorry I could not solve it

Comment: There is a revised list in the bottom of that link page

Comment: I suspect you will still run into errors as 'ACN' among others are outdated connections.

Comment: Error is not my problem. r percieved a lot of correct symbols but giving a few output in global environmet. which are in alphabetic order.

Comment: yes when I run all codes together ( the bottom codes of that page) still it gives four outputs but some error. But I tried line by line. In that case it also give some output . like around 13 output in Alphabetic order. Initilal Names which started by A

Comment: So yes, it seems an error is your problem. Please see my answer below, it works for me. Review your terminal output to see which 'companies' are throwing errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially what is happening is your function `getSymbols` is breaking once it hits the first error at 'ACN'. To skip over bad connections and just read in the good connections use the following code. Add in `from` parameter to adjust time.

```
quantmod_list <- c('AAPL', 'ABT', 'ABBV', 'ACN', 'ACE', 'ADBE', 'ADT', 'AAP', 'AES', 'AET', 'AFL','AMG', 'A', 'GAS', 'ARE', 'APD', 'AKAM', 'AA', 'AGN', 'ALXN', 'ALLE', 'ADS', 'ALL', 'ALTR', 'MO', 'AMZN', 'AEE', 'AAL', 'AEP', 'AXP', 'AIG', 'AMT', 'AMP', 'ABC', 'AME', 'AMGN', 'APH', 'APC', 'ADI', 'AON', 'APA', 'AIV', 'AMAT', 'ADM', 'AIZ', 'T', 'ADSK', 'ADP', 'AN', 'AZO', 'AVGO', 'AVB', 'AVY', 'BHI', 'BLL', 'BAC', 'BK', 'BCR', 'BXLT', 'BAX', 'BBT', 'BDX', 'BBBY', 'BRK.B', 'BBY', 'BLX', 'HRB', 'BA', 'BWA', 'BXP', 'BSX', 'BMY', 'BRCM', 'BF.B', 'CHRW', 'CA', 'CVC', 'COG', 'CAM', 'CPB', 'COF', 'CAH', 'HSIC', 'KMX', 'CCL', 'CAT', 'CBG', 'CBS', 'CELG', 'CNP', 'CTL', 'CERN', 'CF', 'SCHW', 'CHK', 'CVX', 'CMG', 'CB', 'CI', 'XEC', 'CINF', 'CTAS', 'CSCO', 'C', 'CTXS', 'CLX', 'CME', 'CMS', 'COH', 'KO', 'CCE', 'CTSH', 'CL', 'CMCSA', 'CMA', 'CSC', 'CAG', 'COP', 'CNX', 'ED', 'STZ', 'GLW', 'COST', 'CCI', 'CSX', 'CMI', 'CVS', 'DHI', 'DHR', 'DRI', 'DVA', 'DE', 'DLPH', 'DAL', 'XRAY', 'DVN', 'DO', 'DTV', 'DFS', 'DISCA', 'DISCK', 'DG', 'DLTR', 'D', 'DOV', 'DOW', 'DPS', 'DTE', 'DD', 'DUK', 'DNB', 'ETFC', 'EMN', 'ETN', 'EBAY', 'ECL', 'EIX', 'EW', 'EA', 'EMC', 'EMR', 'ENDP', 'ESV', 'ETR', 'EOG', 'EQT', 'EFX', 'EQIX', 'EQR', 'ESS', 'EL', 'ES', 'EXC', 'EXPE', 'EXPD', 'ESRX', 'XOM', 'FFIV', 'FB', 'FAST', 'FDX', 'FIS', 'FITB', 'FSLR', 'FE', 'FISV', 'FLIR', 'FLS', 'FLR', 'FMC', 'FTI', 'F', 'FOSL', 'BEN', 'FCX', 'FTR', 'GME', 'GPS', 'GRMN', 'GD', 'GE', 'GGP', 'GIS', 'GM', 'GPC', 'GNW', 'GILD', 'GS', 'GT', 'GOOGL', 'GOOG', 'GWW', 'HAL', 'HBI', 'HOG', 'HAR', 'HRS', 'HIG', 'HAS', 'HCA', 'HCP', 'HCN', 'HP', 'HES', 'HPQ', 'HD', 'HON', 'HRL', 'HSP', 'HST', 'HCBK', 'HUM', 'HBAN', 'ITW', 'IR', 'INTC', 'ICE', 'IBM', 'IP', 'IPG', 'IFF', 'INTU', 'ISRG', 'IVZ', 'IRM', 'JEC', 'JBHT', 'JNJ', 'JCI', 'JOY', 'JPM', 'JNPR', 'KSU', 'K', 'KEY', 'GMCR', 'KMB', 'KIM', 'KMI', 'KLAC', 'KSS', 'KRFT', 'KR', 'LB', 'LLL', 'LH', 'LRCX', 'LM', 'LEG', 'LEN', 'LVLT', 'LUK', 'LLY', 'LNC', 'LLTC', 'LMT', 'L', 'LOW', 'LYB', 'MTB', 'MAC', 'M', 'MNK', 'MRO', 'MPC', 'MAR', 'MMC', 'MLM', 'MAS', 'MA', 'MAT', 'MKC', 'MCD', 'MCK', 'MJN', 'MMV', 'MDT', 'MRK', 'MET', 'KORS', 'MCHP', 'MU', 'MSFT', 'MHK', 'TAP', 'MDLZ', 'MON', 'MNST', 'MCO', 'MS', 'MOS', 'MSI', 'MUR', 'MYL', 'NDAQ', 'NOV', 'NAVI', 'NTAP', 'NFLX', 'NWL', 'NFX', 'NEM', 'NWSA', 'NEE', 'NLSN', 'NKE', 'NI', 'NE', 'NBL', 'JWN', 'NSC', 'NTRS', 'NOC', 'NRG', 'NUE', 'NVDA', 'ORLY', 'OXY', 'OMC', 'OKE', 'ORCL', 'OI', 'PCAR', 'PLL', 'PH', 'PDCO', 'PAYX', 'PNR', 'PBCT', 'POM', 'PEP', 'PKI', 'PRGO', 'PFE', 'PCG', 'PM', 'PSX', 'PNW', 'PXD', 'PBI', 'PCL', 'PNC', 'RL', 'PPG', 'PPL', 'PX', 'PCP', 'PCLN', 'PFG', 'PG', 'PGR', 'PLD', 'PRU', 'PEG', 'PSA', 'PHM', 'PVH', 'QRVO', 'PWR', 'QCOM', 'DGX', 'RRC', 'RTN', 'O', 'RHT', 'REGN', 'RF', 'RSG', 'RAI', 'RHI', 'ROK', 'COL', 'ROP', 'ROST', 'RLD', 'R', 'CRM', 'SNDK', 'SCG', 'SLB', 'SNI', 'STX', 'SEE', 'SRE', 'SHW', 'SPG', 'SWKS', 'SLG', 'SJM', 'SNA', 'SO', 'LUV', 'SWN', 'SE', 'STJ', 'SWK', 'SPLS', 'SBUX', 'HOT', 'STT', 'SRCL', 'SYK', 'STI', 'SYMC', 'SYY', 'TROW', 'TGT', 'TEL', 'TE', 'TGNA', 'THC', 'TDC', 'TSO', 'TXN', 'TXT', 'HSY', 'TRV', 'TMO', 'TIF', 'TWX', 'TWC', 'TJX', 'TMK', 'TSS', 'TSCO', 'RIG', 'TRIP', 'FOXA', 'TSN', 'TYC', 'UA', 'UNP', 'UNH', 'UPS', 'URI', 'UTX', 'UHS', 'UNM', 'URBN', 'VFC', 'VLO', 'VAR', 'VTR', 'VRSN', 'VZ', 'VRTX', 'VIAB', 'V', 'VNO', 'VMC', 'WMT', 'WBA', 'DIS', 'WM', 'WAT', 'ANTM', 'WFC', 'WDC', 'WU', 'WY', 'WHR', 'WFM', 'WMB', 'WEC', 'WYN', 'WYNN', 'XEL', 'XRX', 'XLNX', 'XL', 'XYL', 'YHOO', 'YUM', 'ZBH', 'ZION', 'ZTS')

for(company in quantmod_list){
  try(getSymbols(company, auto.assign = TRUE, src="google"))
  print(company)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Everything is ok.